# Basic Program with Random Number Generator

Tags: python

The program should be:
Write a program named numbers.py that generates ten random integers, all from 1-100, and stores them in a list. Use a loop. Use a second loop to process the list. In this latter loop, display all numbers in the list and determine the sum of the odd numbers and the sum of the even numbers. Display these sums after the second loop has ended.

So far I have the first part.

```
import random

def main():
    for count in range(10):
        print(random.randint(1, 100))

main()
```

My question is how do I get the sums of the odds/evens.  I don't want the rest completely written just need to know how I go about it.

Comment: You're printing the numbers, not exactly storing them in a list.

Comment: You need one variable to keep track of the sum of the even numbers, and one to keep track of the odd numbers.  For each item in the list you need to test if it is even or odd. Hint: for an even number x, x%2==0, and for an odd number x, x%2==1.

Answer (score 0):

instead of printing store the numbers in list

```
import random

def main():
    my_list = []
    for count in range(10):
        my_list.append(random.randint(1, 100)))
     return my_list
 my_list = main()
 sum_even = sum([x for x in my_list if x%2==0 ])
 sum_odd = sum([X for x in my_list if x%2!=0 ])
 print(sum_even,sum_odd)
```

if your case `random.sample` will be better:

```
my_list = random.sample(range(100),100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code that could be used to add the numbers to your list

```
listOfNumbers = list()
listOfNumbers.append( random.randint(1, 100) )
```

This could be used to iterate through your list

```
for s in listOfNumbers :
```

This can check if its a even number

```
if (s % 2 == 0):
```

otherwise its odd.

Some basic math can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you with pseudo code, so you can transelate it to python yourself ;) Just like you asked

```
import random

def main():
    # Initialize a list
    for count in range(10):
        # Add this to that list
        print(random.randint(1, 100))
    # Init two variables. One for even one for odds
    # Loop through list
        # if even:
            # Add to even
        # else:
            # add to odd


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following may help you:

```
import random

randomlist = [random.randint(1, 100) for item in range(10)]

odd_numbers = []
even_numbers = []
print "Random list: "
for item in randomlist:
   print item
   if item % 2 == 0:
      even_numbers.append(item)
   elif item % 2 != 0:
      odd_numbers.append(item)

print "Odd Numbers: ", odd_numbers
print "Even Numbers: ", even_numbers
```

Comment: Read the assignement. He needs two loops.

Comment: There are two loops used. One is at line # 3 and one is at line # 8. I'm just trying to show him on how to use the for loop in the list comprehension also.

Comment: Also OP asked you not to write the code but to help him on the way.

Comment: My answer is not completed though. He wanted the sum of even and odd numbers. I helped him on how to determine the even and odd number.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  I got it figured out now.  I appreciate the help on something most of you know as simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import random
>>> my_list = map(lambda x:(random.randint(1,100)), range(10))
>>> my_list
[3, 85, 22, 98, 77, 66, 100, 26, 35, 46]
>>> even_list, odd_list = [],[]
>>> for num in my_list:
...     if num%2 == 0:
...         even_list.append(num)
...     else:
...         odd_list.append(num)
...
>>> print "Sum of even numbers:", sum(even_list)
Sum of even numbers: 358
>>> print "Sum of odd numbers:", sum(odd_list)
Sum of odd numbers: 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres my version

I know it does not have the even and odd number filter but you can try to add that from the other answers

```
from random import randrange as randomInt

numberList = []

for i in range(10):
    number = randomInt(1,100)
    numberList.append(number)

for number in numberList:
    print(number)
```